# Compass blueprint mixins undefined

Tags: css, haml, sass, compass-sass, blueprint-css

I am trying to get compass/sass/haml working using blueprint but not having any luck with the blueprint mixins

```
+column(24)
```

just results in Sass syntax error undefined mixin column

I'm sure I am just missing something really obvious but the compass/haml/sass/bluprint combo is just so many things at once I can't sort it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
+blueprint
```

like i said.  Something really obvious.  doh!

Comment: As further clarification this is because of a compass design decision to default to encouraging people to explicitly include blueprint module by module.

Comment: `+blueprint` is going to add the blueprint classes to your stylesheets which you may have wanted, but maybe not. All you really need to have is `@import blueprint` in your sass file to access the grid mixins but you can be more selective if you like. E.g. `@import blueprint/grid`